# Azure Storage modify file easily like a file system

Tags: azure

I use a excel file as file input of a workerRole on azure cloud. Everyday this file is checked by the workerRole. This file is store on Azure Storage

I wanna ofter the capabilities to my customer to modify easily this file. So I tried with Azure Explorer. He can see the file, open it, BUT when Azure Explorer open it, a copy is created in local. So when you save, modifications stay in local. So the customer has to override the file with the new version manually.

Is there a way to do it without the manually override at the end ? An other soft ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do it directly. Azure Storage is not a filesystem like OneDrive or your local drive.

However, there are workarounds like exposing Azure Storage like a File Share to the local computer of the user through WebDav. Maybe is not the best solution but it's a workaround: http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/mounting-your-azure-file-shares-on-premises-through-webdav/

Comment: thanks. I looking for a solution very simple for my customer. Yours works but isn't simple enough.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said it was a workaround. Maybe you can try to use the OneDrive API. You can upload a file there and share the link with the user. After that, the user can access with it's account and modify the file directly from the browser using Excel Online or modify it from it's Excel installed on it's machine and keep the files synced. To create a file -> https://dev.onedrive.com/items/create.htm , to share a file -> https://dev.onedrive.com/items/sharing_createLink.htm